# UILabels is blurry with autolayout

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I'm starting my first experiments with `autolayout`. Everything is ok, but I faced on problem: my `UILabel`s now is blurry. Again.

I faced same problem when I made my first steps with iOS without `autolayout` and it was solved very simple:

```
[label setFrame:CGRectIntegral(label.frame)];
```

But. Now I can't `setFrame` with `autolayout` and looks like my labels coordinates is floating number.

How can I fix that? How can I change my constraints to prevent floating `UILabel` coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried this in an actual device, I have been in the situation where stuff has appeared blurry in the simulator but not the device.
It is also probable because you labels location is not rounded to the nearest integer, its possible that auto layout is rounding to the nearest 0.5, which on retina display is a whole device pixel.